# Publishing on Facebook fan page with Python

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I tried a couple of codes about how to publish on Facebook wall. But I would like do a little bit different. I wonder publish in my facebook fan page. The following code just publish on my personal profile. Can any one give me a clue to publish in fan page?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import facebook
import urllib 
import urlparse

FACEBOOK_APP_ID = 'X'
FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET = 'Y'
FACEBOOK_PROFILE_ID = 'MyProfileId (**not page id, right?**)'

oauth_args = dict(client_id     = FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
                  client_secret = FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET,
                  grant_type    = 'client_credentials')

oauth_response = urllib.urlopen('https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?' + urllib.urlencode(oauth_args)).read()                                  
page_token='PAGE TOKEN GOT INhttps://graph.facebook.com/SITE' 
fields=access_token
attach = {
  "name": 'Hello world',
  "link": 'http://www.example.com',
  "caption": 'test post',
  "description": 'some test',
  "picture" : 'http://www.example.com/picture.jpg',
  "page_token" : page_token
}
try:
    oauth_access_token = urlparse.parse_qs(str(oauth_response))['access_token'][0]
except KeyError:
    raise
print oauth_access_token
facebook_graph = facebook.GraphAPI(oauth_access_token)
try:
    response = facebook_graph.put_wall_post('', attachment=attach,profile_id = FACEBOOK_PROFILE_ID)
except facebook.GraphAPIError as e:
    print e
```

Comment: Get a page access token, and post to the feed connection of your page. It’s all in the FB docs, have a look.

Comment: I already got page access token, but I still have problems. First I got "Posts where the actor is a page cannot also include a target_id" then I removed the FACEBOOK_PROFILE_ID from put_wall_post and I got " Subject must be a page."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I corrected the code, here is the solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# coding: utf-8

import facebook
import urllib 
import urlparse

access_token_page='X'
FACEBOOK_APP_ID = 'Y'
FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET = 'Z'
FACEBOOK_PROFILE_ID = 'W'

oauth_args = dict(client_id     = FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
                  client_secret = FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET,
                  grant_type    = 'client_credentials')

oauth_response = urllib.urlopen('https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?' + urllib.urlencode(oauth_args)).read()                                  

attach = {
  "name": 'Hello world',
  "link": 'http://www.example.com',
  "caption": 'test post',
  "description": 'some test',
  "picture" : 'http://www.example.com/picture.jpg',
}


facebook_graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token_page)
try:
    response = facebook_graph.put_wall_post('', attachment=attach)
except facebook.GraphAPIError as e:
    print e
```

Information about authentication can be get in: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/pages/

Comment: Does this actually post to a fan page or just a specific user's stream? I don't see any details regarding the actual fan page.